# image is not getting displayed in rails 6 views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, checkbox, collections, rails-activestorage

i have the following code in my rails 6 app . using active storage for saving images to the database

```
<%= form_for(@business, url: supplier_save_business_categories_path, :html => {method: :post } ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
     <%= b.label class: "check_box" do%>
       <%#= image_tag(url_for(b.image)) if b.image.present? %> image is not getting displayed here.
       <%=b.check_box style: "display: none;"%> <%= b.text %>
     < %end%>
<% end %>
```

trying to display category image like this.

```
<%#= image_tag(url_for(b.image)) if b.image.present? %>
```

but the image is not getting displayed here. when category name is getting displayed from db from category record, i do not know why the category image is not getiing displayed.

getting the following error.

```
undefined method `image' for #<ActionView::Helpers::Tags::CollectionCheckBoxes::CheckBoxBuilder:0x00007fb6205a48c0>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [officiel docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) you can see that the `collection_check_boxes` method is intended to give you a checkbox with a value(usual an id) and a label(usual a name/text). Since you have the id of the record, you could go find the record and get the image url offcourse. Something like this:

```rb
<%= form_for(@business, url: supplier_save_business_categories_path, :html => {method: :post } ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
     <%= b.label class: "check_box" do%>
       <%= image_tag(url_for(category_image(b.id))) unless category_image(b.id).nil? %>
       <%=b.check_box style: "display: none;"%> <%= b.text %>
     < % end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

# CategoryHelper
def category_image(category_id)
  category = Category.find(category_id)
  if category
    category.image
  else
    nil
  end
end
```